Express JS connect-flash requires manual additional page reload
My flash messages seem to require an additional manual reload of the page for them to appear.
Here's an example of how I'm using it:
    if (password.length < 12) {
      req.flash('error', 'Password must be at least 12 characters long.');
      return res.redirect('/signup');
    }

It then redirects to /signup which displays this pug view:
extends auth

block content
  h4.card-title Sign Up

  // Debug output for flash messages
  pre= JSON.stringify(flashMessages)

  if flashMessages.error
    .alert.alert-danger
    each msg in flashMessages.error
      div= msg


Upon redirect, no errors are displayed but if I refresh the page, the errors then appear.
Here's where I configure it:
// Initialize Session Store
const SequelizeStore = require('connect-session-sequelize')(session.Store);

// Initialize Express Web App
const app = express();

// add various locals
app.locals.config = config;
app.locals.moment = moment;

// Initialize HTTP Server
const server = http.createServer(app);

//app.use(cookieParser(process.env.APP_KEY)); apparently don't need this with express-session 1.15 and later (we have 1.18)

// setup morgan to log HTTP requests to winston
app.use(morgan('tiny', { stream: { write: message => logger.debug(message.trim()) } }));

// Initialize Session
const sessionStore = new SequelizeStore({ db: sequelize });

app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.APP_KEY,
    store: sessionStore, // Use SequelizeStore as the session store
    resave: false, // 'resave' and 'saveUninitialized' set as per express-session recommendations
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' }
}));

// Sync the session store table
sessionStore.sync();

I tried searching for a solution but couldn't find one.
Thanks in advance
